# Nginx not catching subdomain

Tags: nginx, subdomain, configuration

I have added a subdomain:

http://vma.ottawakaraoke.com/

However it is serving back the root of an entirely different subdomain. Its serving up the content from http://summitent.ca/ - a totally different domain.

Q1. How do I debug this, will nginx tell me somewhere that it couldn't find the right folder?

Q2. Is something missing in my config? Why can't it find the root folder? Do I need an alias?

Q3. Where is the best nginx doco. nginx has been a massive PITA for me so far.

Q4. Does it not like dots in filepaths?

I have changed permission ownership of the directory and yes, I have restarted nginx. Here is my config. Any help would be great!

```
server {
server_name vma.ottawakaraoke.com;
access_log /var/www/vma.ottawakaraoke.com/logs/access.log;
error_log /var/www/vma.ottawakaraoke.com/logs/error.log;
root /var/www/vma.ottawakaraoke.com/public_html/;

location / {
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
} }
```

Comment: Did you actually include this configuration into nginx's config? Where did you put it?

Comment: /etc/nginx/sites-available/vma.ottawakaraoke.com - and yes I have the include in my global nginx. Is there a way to confirm its getting read in by nginx?

Comment: So you remembered to put the symlink in sites-enabled?

Comment: yep :) - that should be all good. I would imagine if it couldn't pick up the config then vma.ottawakaraoke.com would be a 404 right?

Comment: No, it would just return a different site on the same server. Which is what it appears to be doing.

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 Jul 14 11:11 vma.ottawakaraoke.com -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/vma.ottawakaraoke.com

Comment: OK, so why is summitent.ca being served from this 1&1 server at all, when it is apparently on some other server in Florida?

Comment: its a TMZ server, the DNS is on 1&1 - I have no idea, this dudes setup is strange

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because you don't have a default server specified.

Change this line:

```
server_name vma.ottawakaraoke.com;
```

to this:

```
server_name vma.ottawakaraoke.com default_server;
```

Comment: ill try it but seems unlikely